# Powerful disk editor for Linux like Acronis Disk Editor

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, hex-editor, acronis-diskdirector

I would like to have a powerful Linux-based disk viewer / editor (raw hex editor) like Acronis Disk Editor. It should show the absolute sector, cylinder, head and relative sector for the part you are looking at, and you can search and go to positions, etc.

Here is a picture:

[image: Acronis Disk Editor screenshot with details]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Active@ Disk Editor as it is freeware Windows and Linux and in my opinion a better all around tool then Acronis due to many useful features.   It meets most of your requirements along with some very useful features without being cluttered.  Very similar to Acronis Disk Editor it is a powerful hard drive raw hex editor which shows your current sector and offset as well as having the ability to goto any location on the disk and find locations by searching for ANSI, Hex, or Unicode strings.

[Active@ Disk Editor uses a simple, low-level disk viewer which displays information in binary and text modes at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hSYE.gif)

It also supports location bookmarks, drive and partition table formatted data templates to format data as well as tools for recognizing partition tables, MBR, file headers and much more.

I am no way affiliated with any company, I was just looking for a similar tool and found this along with your question during my search.

**Here is information from the Company:**

> Active@ Disk Editor is a freeware advanced tool for viewing & editing
>   raw sectors on Physical Disks, Partitions & Files content in
>   hexadecimal form.
>
> http://www.disk-editor.org

**Software features:**

```
Enhanced template view FAT, NTFS, UFS, HFS+, ExtFs templates (iNodes,SuperBlocks)
Detailed MFT record information
Side-by-side Compare and Edit
Fields coloring with data in tooltips
Extensive exFAT support
Fast navigation points
Filling selection with a pattern
Unicode support
Quick Disk Info
Bookmarks
Data Inspector
Hyperlinks for MFT records
Advanced search using RegExp & wildcards
Open and work with raw & compressed disk images
Command line support
More templates supported (HFS+, Linux)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of that software.

Comment: I've tried it but doesn't work with removable drives. The option is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the tool you need: http://www.wxhexeditor.org/home.php,
just use `sudo apt-get install wxhexeditor`

Well, I guess, you could also use `dd` and `hexdump` in some form.
If you use SATA, you would look for `/dev/sdX` for NVMe drives that would be `/dev/nvme0n1p3` like this:

`` sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 bs=1k count=1 | hexdump -C
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB, 1.0 KiB) copied, 2.4685e-05 s, 41.5 MB/s
00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 74 73 2d 70 6c 61 69  |........xts-plai|
00000030  6e 36 34 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |n64.............|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00  |........sha256..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 40  |...............@|
00000070  a4 95 e1 f5 c9 ee d0 30  6c 4e 37 f2 fb af a4 2a  |.......0lN7....*|
00000080  14 f9 89 0b b5 89 14 a5  76 c4 5a af a0 2f 3e 64  |........v.Z../>d|
00000090  10 82 4c f6 3c 01 b3 c6  11 ff 5f 37 e4 46 8b 88  |..L.<....._3.F..|
000000a0  f5 7c 83 6e 00 03 08 5e  36 64 65 31 61 62 39 34  |.|.n...^6de1ab94|
000000b0  2d 61 35 34 64 2d 34 32  66 30 2d 39 32 64 31 2d  |-a54d-42f0-12d1-|
000000c0  65 65 66 62 62 63 32 30  63 61 38 66 00 00 00 00  |eefbbc20ca8f....|
000000d0  00 ac 71 f3 00 18 43 2c  62 fd 14 d0 fe 8c ac e0  |..q...H,b.......|
000000e0  b7 18 02 d3 40 30 dd c7  2f 50 1a af 1c 75 05 ed  |....@0../P...u..|
000000f0  9b 60 f9 7d c2 e7 d1 1e  00 00 00 08 00 00 0f a0  |.`.}............|
00000100  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 02 00 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000130  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 03 f8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000160  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 05 f0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000190  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 07 e8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001c0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 09 e0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001f0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000210  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0b d8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000220  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000230  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000240  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 0d d0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000250  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000400 ``

You could also use any hex editor, like vim (xxd) or emacs (hexl-mode)
For vim this would be:

`:%!xxd to switch into hex mode
:%!xxd -r to exit from hex mode`

Please consult this different answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498197/need-a-good-hex-editor-for-linux
You can also refer to vim wiki for the editing part: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Hex_dump

So I would do something like this:
`sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 seek=<NUMBER OF BS BLOCKS TO SKIP> bs=1k count=1 | vim -b -`

This is probably not very convenient, but it works almost on any UNIX-like system for the last about 20 years at least.